# Calling view controller method from appdelegate doesn't work when using Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

Good day everyone,

I am not able to call the method refresh in my ViewController when using a Storyboad. However it works if I create the project without the Storyboard, just a NIB. Why it doesn't work and how to overcome this issue?

Here is my code:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    ViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    NSLog(@"app will enter foreground");
    [viewController refresh:NULL]; 
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction) refresh:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)loadData {
    // contains information the ViewController makes use of
}

-(IBAction)refresh:(id) sender {
    [self loadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you have the button connected to the `refresh:` method as it's "action" connection in Xcode?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed my method to the following and still does't work: -(void)refresh:(id) sender {
    [self loadData];
}

Answer (score 2):

The `viewController` property in your app delegate are not populated when using a storyboard. Include the value in your log statement for confirmation - it will be null.

Register your view controller for the notification instead, and let it handle it's own refreshing.

In viewDidLoad:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(refresh:) 
    name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
    object: nil];
```

You'll want to remove this observer in dealloc / viewDidUnload as well.

Comment: thanks for you response. refresh is just the name of my method which I wish to call. How do I register the ViewController for the notification?

Comment: I added this but the app does't even get launch anymore: -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                          selector: @selector(refresh:) 
                                          name: @"NotificationNameHere"
                                          object: nil];
    
    return self;
}

Comment: Put that in viewDidLoad, not initWithCoder. The notification name is UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification.

Comment: I tried the following and it worked: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                          selector: @selector(refresh:) 
                                          name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                          object: nil];